# How to store .txt file data in different columns of a CSV file using BASH?

Tags: bash, csv, file, sed, txt

I have a .txt file with the following data structure:

```
Scan Times:
 33.3 seconds
 77.4 seconds
 33.3 seconds
 77.4 seconds

Check Times:
 110.30 seconds
 72.99 seconds
 72.16 seconds
 110.30 seconds

Move Times:
 73.66 seconds
 90.77 seconds
 72.87 seconds
 71.75 seconds
 
Switch Times:
 92.0 seconds
 78.6 seconds
 77.8 seconds
 84.9 seconds
```

I now want to take that .txt file and create a CSV file that has the following format.

[image]

I have a very basic layout so far with my bash script but I am not sure how to proceed:

```
inputFiles=("./Successes/SuccessSummary.txt" "./Failures/FailSummary.txt")
touch results.csv

for file in "${inputFiles[@]}"
do 
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        #echo $line
        if [ "$line" = "Scan Times:" ]
        then 
        fi

        if [ "$line" = "Check Times:" ]
        then 
        fi

        if [ "$line" = "Move Times:" ]
        then 
        fi
        
        if [ "$line" = "Switch Distances:" ]
        then 
        fi
    done < "$file"
done
```

Comment: have you tried a google search on `bash pivot csv? also, are you trying to write both input files into the same/single output file and if so, please provide sample content of both input files and the desired output (matching the sample data from the input files)

Comment: I have not I will look into bash pivot. Both files are the exact same format so my final CSV should have 8 columns of data. I was planning on using a counter to increment what column my data is being printed into. @markp-fuso

Comment: Please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an `awk` script that does it:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    OFS=","
    colnum=0
}

/:$/ {
    data[++colnum,1]=$0
    rownum=1
}

/seconds$/ {
    data[colnum,++rownum]=$1
}

END {
    for (r = 1; r <= rownum; r++) {
        for (c = 1; c <= colnum; c++) {
            printf "%s%s", data[c,r], (c == colnum ? RS : OFS)
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```sh
$ ./pivot input.txt
Scan Times:,Check Times:,Move Times:,Switch Times:
33.3,110.30,73.66,92.0
77.4,72.99,90.77,78.6
33.3,72.16,72.87,77.8
77.4,110.30,71.75,84.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; FS="\n"; OFS="," }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (i > 1) {
            gsub(/[^0-9.]/,"",$i)
        }
        vals[i,NR] = $i
    }
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=NR; j++) {
            printf "%s%s", vals[i,j], (j<NR ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Scan Times:,Check Times:,Move Times:,Switch Times:
33.3,110.30,73.66,92.0
77.4,72.99,90.77,78.6
33.3,72.16,72.87,77.8
77.4,110.30,71.75,84.9
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable with some help from unix/linux utilities.

With one file.

The script `my_script`

```
#!/bin/sh

ed -s "$1" <<-EOF
 g/.\\{1,\\}/s/^ //\\
 s/ seconds//
 w tmpa.$$
 %d
 r !pr -t4 -s, tmpa.$$
 d
 !rm tmpa.$$
 w result.csv
 %p
 Q
EOF
```

---

Then

```
./myscript ./Successes/SuccessSummary.txt
```

---

The output and content of the `result.csv`

```
Scan Times:,Check Times:,Move Times:,Switch Times:
33.3,110.30,73.66,92.0
77.4,72.99,90.77,78.6
33.3,72.16,72.87,77.8
77.4,110.30,71.75,84.9
```

---

With two files. (Just using the content of the first file with the second.)

```
#!/bin/sh

ed -s "$1" <<-EOF
 g/.\\{1,\\}/s/^ //\\
 s/ seconds//
 w tmpa.$$
 %d
 r !pr -t4 -s, tmpa.$$
 d
 w tmpa.$$
 E $2
 g/.\\{1,\\}/s/^ //\\
 s/ seconds//
 w tmpb.$$
 %d
 r !pr -t4 -s, tmpb.$$
 d
 w tmpb.$$
 %d
 r !pr -mts, tmpa.$$ tmpb.$$
 %p
 w result.csv
 !rm tmp[ab].$$
 Q
EOF
```

---

Then

```
./myscript ./Successes/SuccessSummary.txt ./Failures/FailSummary.txt
```

---

The output and content of the result.csv

```
Scan Times:,Check Times:,Move Times:,Switch Times:,Scan Times:,Check Times:,Move Times:,Switch Times:
33.3,110.30,73.66,92.0,33.3,110.30,73.66,92.0
77.4,72.99,90.77,78.6,77.4,72.99,90.77,78.6
33.3,72.16,72.87,77.8,33.3,72.16,72.87,77.8
77.4,110.30,71.75,84.9,77.4,110.30,71.75,84.9
```

---

- The `ed` script has two temp files `tmpa.$$` and `tmpb.$$` but it is removed/deleted at the line where `!rm tmpa ...` is at.
- The output is written at the file `result.csv`
- `Ed` is a file editor not a scripting/programming language like say `awk` or `bash` and not everyone likes `ed`, but it is still an option/solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed, csplit & paste):

```
sed '/\S/!d;s/^ \| seconds//g' file |
csplit -zs - '/:/' '{*}' && paste -d, xx* && rm xx*
```

Use sed to remove blank lines and unwanted spaces and literals.

Use csplit to split file into separate parts i.e xx00 ...

Use paste to combine the separates parts back into one using a comma as field separator.

Clean up left over files.